# Redmine git integration - issue in accessing git from redmine but not from external git client

Tags: apache-2.2, git, redmine

I have setup redmine integration with apache as described in the redmine documentation. I have a /git path accessible with auth and /git-private accessible only to redmine. When I clone the repository through /git path, I get the up-to-date repo. But when I try to view it in redmine repo viewer, I get a 404 "The entry or revision was not found in the repository." error. Trying to clone using the git-private url in the redmine box gives a bare repository though it is the same repo as the one cloned by the /git path. I have enabled RedmineGitSmartHttp in the /git path. What could be the issue here?

```
PerlLoadModule Apache::Redmine

SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /path/to/git/root
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL

ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/

<Location /git>
      AuthType Basic
      Require valid-user
      AuthName "Git"

      PerlAccessHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::access_handler
      PerlAuthenHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::authen_handler

      RedmineDSN "DBI:mysql:database=<dbname>;host=<db host>" 
      RedmineDbUser "<user>" 
      RedmineDbPass "<password" 

      RedmineGitSmartHttp yes
</Location>

<Location /git-private>
      Order deny,allow
      Deny from all

     <Limit GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         Allow from <redmine public ip>
         Allow from <redmine pvt ip>
         Allow from <localhost>
     </Limit>
</Location>
```

Comment: It seems to me that all the redmine options are only set on `/git` and not `/git-private` but I don't know if that's intentional...

Comment: @DerfK The redmine options are set on /git because that is the path through which the world will access the git repository and hence it has Redmine options pertaining to authentication and access permissions. /git-private is meant only for redmine to use and it just reads the repositories directly over http without requiring any credentials. Is there some issue with this?

Answer (score 0):

Redmine can't access a git repository via HTTP. It **always** needs direct file system access to the bare git repo for showing its content on the Repository tab. Thus your `/git-private` construct will not work at all (although something like this could be done with Subversion)

Consequently, in the repository settings of Redmine, you have to enter a *filesystem path* to the bare git repository, not a URL.

Comment: Isn't it a bad idea to give server paths in redmine? If the server is migrated to another server and the path there changes, then this would require a lot of changes

Comment: Also I have seen a lot of howto's on the internet which use exactly the same method and I don't see how and why redmine cannot access the git repo over http